# Python treat multiple words as single

Tags: python, tf-idf

Is there any method to treat multiple word as single in Python? I've written a script to find Tf-Idf value of words in a collection of documents. The problem is that, it gives the Tf-Idf for individual words. But there are cases where i've to treat multiple word as as one, such as words like  **Big Data** , **Machine Learning** should be treated as a single word and  Tf-Idf score for those word should be calculated. Any help would be highly useful.

Comment: Show some code. Input ? Output ? Expected Output ?

Comment: show code . inputs and expected output will help to solve problem

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it using scikit-learn and the TfidfVectorizer. Tweaking some of it's parameters would basically allow you to do all the work.

It's hard to show it's functionality though without a good example.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = "lots of text"    
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
result = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Know that the `ngram_range` parameter allows you to choose if you are interested in e.g. bigrams, trigrams, etc. by choosing a range.